# Verifying that a path points to another path within a given directory

Tags: node.js

The following node.js function takes a path and successfully checks whether or not it is a symbolic link (printing `true` or `false` to the console, respectively):

```
    var confirmPathNotSymLinked = function(path) {
         var fs = require("fs");
         fs.lstat(path, function(err, stats) {
                          console.log("is this file a symlink?: " + stats.isSymbolicLink());
         });
     }
```

**Question:** How can I now check to see whether or not a path is not just a symbolic link, but a symbolic link which points into a particular directory?

For example, if `/path/to/file1` points to `/the/actual/address/file1`, then how could I make a function `pointsWithin` such that `pointsWithin("/path/to/file1", "/the/actual/address")` returns `true`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`fs.readlink`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readlink_path_callback) for that.

Here's a possible implementation:

```
function pointsWithin(path, dir, cb) {
  fs.lstat(path, function(err, stats) {
    if (err) return cb(err);
    if (! stats.isSymbolicLink()) return cb(new Error('not a symlink'));
    fs.readlink(path, function(err, dest) {
      if (err) return cb(err);
      return cb(null, dest.indexOf(dir) === 0);
    });
  });
};
```